# Using classname as a variable name

Tags: python-3.x

I'm doing data structures and algorithms course. And in the implementation of the list they use the inbuilt class name `list` as their variable name. My question is how it affects the code.

```
Class Singlelinkedlist():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def create_list():
        pass
list = Singlelinkedlist()
list.create_list()
```

Comment: It would help avoid misunderstandings if you edited the question and posted some code.

Comment: I tried to add but I need atleast 10 reputations to add images

Comment: That's because you are not supposed to add images of code. You type code directly into the question. If you indent 4 spaces it will format it as code. Ideally you would make a small example that shows the problem you are having without a bunch of extra code not relevant to the problem.

Comment: Hey it doesn't format it as the code even indent 4 spaces

Comment: I edited it -- you need to add spaces in front of every line. If you look at the edit, you can see how it works.

Comment: It’s not a good idea to shadow the built in names. The code will still work but might cause hard to debug issues down the track if you make a habit of it.

Comment: I saw this code in the course I'm doing.  But i'm still confused that this has any purpose.

Answer (score 0):

`list` is one of the most fundamental data types in Python. Function `list` is a list constructor. Many standard and third-party libraries depend on the existence and correctness of this function. You should never, literally under no circumstances, redefine it. If you want a "list-like" identifier, call it `my_list` or something else.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try something like this:

```
Class list(list):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def create_list():
        pass
my_list = list('999')
my_list.create_list()
```

with this you add your own things to a build in
maybe is that what you mean?

Answer (score -1):

do you meen something like this:

```
#making class
class test():
    #initing class
    def __init__(self, var):
        #make self.var or if you want to: test(7).var
        self.var = var
#getting self.var out of the program
data = test(7).var
#do your thing here
```

Comment: Sorry bro I didnt mean this.  Mark has edited it again. Look at those codes. I mentioned my question above the code. Thanks for the reply.